# Ckan - require login to view certain metadata

Tags: python, ckan

I have a CKAN 2.6.2 installation deployed with a few hundred datasets added using python via the API, including a number of custom fields, added with ckan.action.package_patch(id=i, extras=extra_fields).

I would like to make one of these extra fields visible only if a user has logged in to the organization.

I think either src/ckan/ckan/templates/package/snippets/additional_info.html or src/ckan/ckan/templates/snippets/additional_info.html are the templates used to generate the lines of HTML that I'd like to selectively filter, but I'm stuck on the next step.

Can anyone help with some pointers?

Comment: Note that the API provides the full record, so you'd have to consider what to do about that too if you're going to aim to make part of it private.

Comment: Thanks - good point. Is the code to answer the API call completely separate from the code to present the fields on the web interface? If they are, then I think for our purposes, hiding it entirely via the API, and only allowing it for logged-in web users would be good behaviour for now. I'm just struggling a bit right now to navigate the code and work out where I should be looking...

Answer (score 1):

Extend PackageController, define custom route and from there you will need to call organization_list_for_user action that will return the organizations that user is member of, and choose which extras you will return depending if user is member of organization or not.